# Check if class has nested class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Say I have a class `XXXPriceDocument` that may have an inner class `LargePackageCharge`, how can I check if it does?

Comment: Consider changing the approach, perhaps. While possible in Ruby this breaks a number of "keep code sane" practices.

Comment: Ruby doesn't have nested classes. It does have nested constants, though. Nested classes are something entirely different!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
XXXPriceDocument.constants.include?(:LargePackageCharge)
```

or

```
defined?(XXXPriceDocument::LargePackageCharge)
```

or

```
XXXPriceDocument.const_defined?(:LargePackageCharge)
```

It gets slightly trickier in rails, as constants may not be loaded yet. You will need to get around this with:

```
class Module
  def const_exists?(mod)
    !!const_get(mod) 
  rescue NameError
    false
  end
end

XXXPriceDocument.const_exists?(:LargePackageCharge)
```

Comment: Huh? I was pretty sure `const_get` will trigger autoloading, no?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - `const_get` will, but will also raise an exception if it is not defined. This is why I wrapped it in a rescue statement.

Comment: This doesn't check for a class, though, only for a constant. You still have to `const_get` the object referenced by the constant and check if it `is_a?(Class)`.

Comment: I posted an answer (which you may have seen) that was very close to your `defined?` approach, but I didn't notice that until now. My apologies.